# Laravel blade echo the value doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5, echo, laravel-blade

I have two tables ..

User and UserMeta
I made relationship between them with hasOne().

Model

```
public function user_meta() {

    return $this->hasOne('App\UserMeta');

}
```

Controller

```
public function index() {
    $users = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    return view('users.index')->with('users', $users);
}
```

View

```
@forelse ($users as $user)

  {{ $user->user_meta->country }}

  @empty
  @endforelse
```

This return error

**Trying to get property 'country' of non-object**

---

But here if I use **dd()** like this.

```
@forelse ($users as $user)

  {{ dd($user->user_meta->country) }}

  @empty
  @endforelse
```

I can see the value return correctly. **United State**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dd` stop loop execution for first element. If you uses `dump` helper, you will see this error again after several iterations. You need check for `null`:

```
@forelse ($users as $user)
   @if(!is_null($user->user_meta))
     {{ $user->user_meta->country }}
   @endif    
@empty
@endforelse
```

Comment: Thanks @yrv16 , I didn't know that without checking "null" could output an error.